# как поместить значения name и years в одноимённые переменные с помощью деструктуризации?

Tags: javascript

```
const user1 = {
  name: "John",
  years: 30
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Разве документация недоступна?

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

```js
const user1 = {
  name: "John",
  years: 30
};

let {name, years} = user1;

console.log(name, years);
```